# Web scrape second number between tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am new to Python, and never done HTML. So any help would be appreciated.
I need to extract two numbers: '1062' and '348', from a website's inspect element.
This is my code:

```
page = requests.get("https://www.traderscockpit.com/?pageView=live-nse-advance-decline-ratio-chart")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

Adv = soup.select_one ('.col-sm-6 .advDec:nth-child(1)').text[10:]

Dec = soup.select_two ('.col-sm-6 .advDec:nth-child(2)').text[10:]
```

The website element looks like below:

```
<div class="nifty-header-shade1 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h4>Stocks</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <p class="advDec"><a href="/?pageView=nse-top-gainers" title="Click to view list of Advanced stocks">Advanced:</a> 1062</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <p class="advDec"><a href="/?pageView=nse-top-losers" title="Click to view list of Declined stocks">Declined:</a> 348</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Using my code, am able to extract first number (1062). But unable to extract the second number (348). Can you please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the Pattern is always the same, you can select your elements by text and get its `next_sibling`:

```
adv = soup.select_one('a:-soup-contains("Advanced:")').next_sibling.strip()
dec = soup.select_one('a:-soup-contains("Declined:")').next_sibling.strip()
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.traderscockpit.com/?pageView=live-nse-advance-decline-ratio-chart")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)

adv = soup.select_one('a:-soup-contains("Advanced:")').next_sibling.strip()
dec = soup.select_one('a:-soup-contains("Declined:")').next_sibling.strip()

print(adv, dec)
```

Comment: Mindblowing ! works like a charm. Thank you so so much

Answer (score 1):

If there are always 2 elements, then the simplest way would probably be to destructure the array of selected elements.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.traderscockpit.com/?pageView=live-nse-advance-decline-ratio-chart")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

adv, dec = [elm.next_sibling.strip() for elm in soup.select(".advDec a") ]
print("Advanced:", adv)
print("Declined", dec)
```